# Dynamic vertical line showing current week in timeline

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, timeline

Despite looking at a similar topic I have not been able to solve this yet. I want to create a vertical line that automatically updates with week number in my sheet (not chart). See picture.

Somehow, I can not solve it with conditional formatting. Can you help me with what/how to make the formatting or (preferably) using a macro.

I have illustrated how I want it to look using an inserted figure.

Hope someone can help.

[image: Timeline screen dump]

The formatting takes me to here:

[image: Conditional formatting].

However, the layout/visual is not super good as it over writes what is already in there.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional formatting is a good way to solve this though. Let's say my week numbers are on A1:ZZ1, then using below formula and applying it to the entire table could give you what you want?

```
=A$1=WEEKNUM(TODAY())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It kind of works, however the visual is not super pretty as is over writes what is already in there...
I have attached the picture in the original question.